# Use JavaScript/jQuery to create custom named HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is this possible? Something like : Pseudo code - createElement("myCustomHTML"). And then you can style myCustomHTML in your CSS. Usage: `<myCustomHTML></myCustomHTML>` which would pull styling in from CSS and be used in jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine; this is how HTML5 elements are used in older browsers.

However, IE won't apply CSS to the elements until you call `document.createElement("elementName")`.
[This is what the HTML5 Shiv does](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/).

Comment: Oh ok, how do i do it then? Or did i inadvertantly write it in my pseudo code?

Comment: @benhowdle: He's talking about IE6, which is (hopefully) an unsupported browser at this point.

Comment: @Josh: Actually, _all_ IE versions, except maybe IE9.

Comment: @ben: In IE, call `document.createElement("tagName")` once.  Then (or in real browsers), just use the element.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, I didn't know that. My question is why not us a `<div>` with an id?